# Format the number of decimal points

Tags: shell-script, text-formatting, numeric-data

I want to slice the 5th column down to three decimal points and put it with first column.

Input

```
                 Accuracy Precision Recall F-measure      s.d
 bemkl_J_DIFP    0.6001   0.01545 0.4304   0.02984    0.016098
 bemkl_J_DI      0.6011   0.01390 0.3870   0.02684    0.013959
 bemkl_J_FP      0.4831   0.01424 0.3609   0.02740    0.015979
```

OutputFile

```
                 Accuracy      Precision Recall   F-measure
bemkl_J_DIFP  0.6001(0.016)     0.01545   0.4304   0.02984
bemkl_J_DI    0.6011(0.013)     0.01390   0.3870   0.02684
bemkl_J_FP    0.4831(0.015)     0.01424   0.3609   0.02740
```

Command:

```
awk -F" " '$6>0 { print substr($6,1,5)}' filename| awk '{print "("$0")"}'
```

Comment: awk -F" " '$6>0 { print substr($6,1,5)}' filename

Comment: As you're using AWK in your comment, note that `printf "%.3f", $6` actually cuts the field down to three decimal places, regardless of how many digits are before the point, unlike `substr`

Comment: I think you mean the 6th column - not the 5th column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat 1.awk
BEGIN { FS = " " ; }
NR == 1  { printf "%26s %16s %8s %11s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 }
NR > 1   { printf "%-15s %s(%0.2g)      %s    %s    %s\n", $1, $2, $6, $3, $4, $5 }
$ awk -f 1.awk infile
                  Accuracy        Precision   Recall   F-measure
bemkl_J_DIFP    0.6001(0.016)      0.01545    0.4304    0.02984
bemkl_J_DI      0.6011(0.014)      0.01390    0.3870    0.02684
bemkl_J_FP      0.4831(0.016)      0.01424    0.3609    0.02740
```